# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when I create a project in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

When I try to execute a project after creating it using the command `meteor`, I get the following error:

```
C: \ Users \ c \ AppData \ Local \ .meteor \ packages \ meteor-tool \ 1.7.0_3 \ mt-os.windows.x86_64 \ dev_bundle \ lib \ node_modules \ meteor-promise \ promise_server.js: 218 

throw error; 
^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

And then when I use `npm start` I get the error:

```
> basic-app @ start C: \ Users \ c \ Desktop \ basic-app
> meteor run

C: \ Users \ c \ AppData \ Local \ .meteor \ packages \ meteor-tool \ 1.7.0_3 
   \mt-os.windows.x86_64 \ dev_bundle \ lib \ node_modules \ meteor-promise \ 
    promise_server.js: 218
    throw error;
    ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! basic-app @ start: `meteor run` 
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the basic-app @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR! C: \ Users \ c \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm-cache \ _logs \ 2018-07- 
 13T17_14_43_857Z-debug.log
```

This is the default `package.json`:

```
 {                                                                                               
    "name": "basic-app",                                                                          
    "private": true,                                                                              
    "scripts": {                                                                                  
      "start": "meteor run",                                                                      
      "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",                          
      "test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package 
                   meteortesting:mocha",     
      "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"                       
     },                                                                                            
    "dependencies": {                                                                             
      "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.51",                                                         
      "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1"                                                               
    },                                                                                            
   "meteor": {                                                                                   
     "mainModule": {                                                                             
       "client": "client/main.js",                                                               
       "server": "server/main.js"                                                                
      },                                                                                          
     "testModule": "tests/main.js"                                                               
    }                                                                                             
  }
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: What's your version of npm? `npm -v`

Comment: The version is 6.1.0

Answer (score 3):

Was experiencing the same issue. In my case I had another node_modules folder at `C:\Users\UserName\node_modules`, renamed this one to node_modules_old and the problem seemed to be solved. 
 I think the node_modules folder inside .meteor `C: \ Users \ c \ AppData \ Local \ .meteor \ packages \ meteor-tool \ 1.7.0_3 \ mt-os.windows.x86_64 \ dev_bundle \ lib \ node_modules` and the node_module folder `C:\Users\UserName\node_modules` conflicted, changing the name seemed to help.
Check these issue if the problem persists: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7896 
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9586